# Aber du hast es nicht getan/du bist es nicht

Tags: colloquial

Kann man die beiden austauschbar verwenden?

> Ich dachte, du kämest, aber du hast es nicht getan.

> Ich dachte, du kämest, aber du bist es nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Die Sätze sind beide ein wenig unüblich und künstlich: Ein Konjunktiv 2 (kämest) in Dialogsätzen (du) außerhalb berichteter Rede (du hast gesagt, du kämst) oder Popmusik-Lyrik erscheint mir sehr gehoben, eine Art älterer-Germanistikprofessor-Sprache. Um hier überhaupt urteilen zu können, muss ich die Sätze für mich erst einmal 'normalisieren':

1. *Ich dachte, du würdest kommen, aber das war leider nicht der Fall* (mit 'tun' ist für mich keine akzeptable Fortsetzung möglich).
2. *Ich dachte, du wärst gekommen, aber das warst / bist du nicht* (nämlich 'gekommen').

Den ersten von dir genannten Satz halte ich für stilistisch unglücklich. Im zweiten Satz setzt eine derartige Reduktion um das Partizip *gekommen* im Fortsetzungssatz nach meinem Gefühl voraus, dass beide Sätze syntaktisch parallel konstruiert sind, nämlich beide mit einem Perfekt-Tempus (Präsens- und Präteritum-Perfekt) und nicht im ersten Satz eine nicht-zusammensetzte [käm(e)st] und im Folgesatz eine zusammengesetzte Zeitform [bist / warst (+ weggelassenes *gekommen*)].

Für die 'aber'-Fortsetzung gibt es einen ganzen Katalog von teils idiomatischen Fortsetzungsmöglichkeiten: *aber da hatte ich mich wohl getäuscht / aber Pustekuchen / dem war (leider) nicht so*, usw. Der *aber*-Satz kann jedoch auch ohne eigentlichen Bedeutungsverlust wegbleiben:

1.' *Ich dachte eigentlich, du würdest kommen.*

2.'  *Ich dachte eigentlich, du wärst gekommen.*

Aus den Beispielen geht nicht hervor, in welcher Situation sie geäußert werden soll. Ist der Sprecher überhaupt 'Betroffener'? Richtig Sinn machen sie nur, wenn zur Situation des vergeblichen Wartens schon ein zeitlicher Abstand besteht. Wenn der säumige Dialogpartner noch die Chance haben soll, verspätet zu erscheinen, könnte man vielleicht sagen:

3.' *Wolltest du nicht längst hier sein?*

Comment: apropos tun: "Ich dachte, du kämest, aber Du tatest es nicht." Ja, umständlich - einfach: "Ich dachte, Du kämest, aber Du kamst nicht." Dagegen auf jeden Fall falsch "Du bist nicht.". "Ich dachte du würdest kommen, ab Du bist (es nicht/nicht gekommen)." Dgg. "du wärst gekommen": Ganz andere Zeit.